# Rally: Collapse rows of rallygridboard

Tags: row, rally

I create an rally taskboard app by using the following source code: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/taskboard

Now I want to set default value for collapsed property in rowConfig but it is not working. otherwise when I use setCollapsed for all rows by using this code:

```js
var rows = this.down('rallycardboard').getRows();
rows[0].setCollapsed(true);
```

It's not working too. Anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently a configuration property for controlling whether a row is expanded or collapsed on load (although they do remember their collapsed state once they are manually clicked on to collapse).

However you should be able to collapse them on load using code very similar to what you have above:

```
var board = this.down('rallycardboard'),
    rows = board.getRows();
rows[0].collapse();
```